# jQuery $.post() Logging Me Out On Key Down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I have a dynamic drop down search bar which searches through the members of a data base inside of a form on my webpage. In order to view this webpage you must log in first. When I built the site on my domain everything works just fine. However when I transferred my files over to a different domain and configed it with an identical database everything works perfect, except my dynamic search in this form. If I type my name (sometime the odd different name with work) in the search everything works fine, but if i type anyone else it seems to stay on the page as it should, but it logs me out and reload the login form on top of everything else including my form I was typing on. I am using jQuery .post() to make the search dynamic. I will provide code below

index.php

```
  <script>
        // this is the jQuery function used to post to the search document on key up
        function searchUserQ(){
            var searchTxt = $("input[name='userSearch']").val();
            console.log(searchTxt);
            if (searchTxt != '') {

                $.post("includes/search.php", {searchVal:searchTxt},
                    function(output){
                        $("#userResults").html(output);
                    });
            }
        }
    </script>


  <h1 class="editUser">Edit User</h1>
  <form class="editUser" action="index.php" method="post">
    <h1>Search For Employee</h1>
    <input type="text" name="userSearch" id="userSearch" placeholder="Search For Employee By First Name" onkeyup="searchUserQ();" />
    <submit type="submit" />
    <div id="userResults">

    </div>
 </form>
```

Search.php

```
<?php
    // Connect To Secure Login
    $cfgProgDir = '../phpSecurePages/';
    include($cfgProgDir . "secure.php");
    //These are the includes needed to make the php page run
    // this file connects to the database
    include("connect.inc.php");

    if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
        // turn that the user searched into a varible
        $searchQ = $_POST['searchVal'];
        // delete any symbols for security
        $searchQ = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchQ);

        $output      = "";
        $link        = "";
        $searchArray = array();
        $searchIndex = 0;

        // Search through these columns inside the main database
        $userSearchQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealerEmployees WHERE 
            firstName   LIKE '%$searchQ%' 
        ");

        // count the number of results
        $userCount = mysql_num_rows($userSearchQuery);
        if($userCount == 0){
            // $output = "There Were No Search Results";
        }else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userSearchQuery)){
                // define dynamic varibles for each loop iteration
                $id         = $row['id'];
                $firstName  = $row['firstName'];
                $lastName   = $row['lastName'];
                $address    = $row['address'];
                $phone      = $row['phone'];
                $email      = $row['email'];
                $password   = $row['password'];
                $permission = $row['permission'];
                $photo      = "images/" . $row['profilePhoto'];

                $output .= "<li><div class='employeeSearch' style=\"background: url('$photo'); width: 75px; height: 75px\"></div><h6>" . $firstName  . "</h6>" . " " .  "<h6>" . $lastName . "</h6><a href='#' class='employee' data-firstName='$firstName' data-lastName='$lastName' data-address='$address' data-phone='$phone' data-email='$email' data-password='$password' data-permission='$permission' data-id='$id'>Select Employee</a></li>";
            }
        }
    }

    echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
> "SELECT id, firstName, lastName, address, phone, email, password,
> permission profilePhone  FROM dealerEmployees WHERE 
>             firstName = '".$searchQ."' Limit 1"
```

Maybe the like condition is giving more than 1 result.

Comment: When I use what you provided above it doesnt sign out as much but if I search for certain users when I delete a letter now it will cause the same issues as before

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a select count(id) as id from dealerEmployees where firstName = '".$searchQ."' and check the count with an if clausule. Maybe the problem you have is too many users with the same firstName.

Answer (score 0):

So After some testing i found out what was happening. When the search would load the search results it would change the password variable in the session to the password of the user coming up in the search since both variables had the same name, all I needed to do was change the var name of the password variable in the search results to be different than the sessions password.

Thanks for all the help!!!